# Create Duplicate Event based on Multi-Picklist Values Initials

Tags: apex, activities

We keep attendees list(Initials) under Event/Activity people who attended meetings. Now I want to create duplicate records for these attendees, so they would get credit for attending the meeting. So, I have started this code, but I am stuck where I am checking to see if UserId's initial matches Attendees' Initial. I could create two for loops but I think this is not efficient. Also, I am fetching all the active users and checking against Attendee's initial. FYI, We store initial under User page. Thank you in advance!

```
    public class cloneEvents {
@InvocableMethod(label='Clone Events' description='Clone Events')
    public static void getClonedInovakable(List<Id> activityId) {

        //fetch all fields related to activity id
        System.debug('Print the list' + activityId);
        List<Event> queryEvent = [
            SELECT Attendees__c,    Assigned_Initial__c  From Event WHERE id=:activityId
        ];


        //Fetch all users and their initials 
        Map <id,User> userMap = new map<id, User>([SELECT id, Initials__c FROM user WHERE IsActive = True]);



        //I am not sure how to check Attendees Initial inside userMap
        for(Event e:queryEvent){
            String[] tempString=  e.Attendees__c.split(';');
            for(String t:tempString){
                 system.debug('str: ' + userMap.contains(t));
        // Check if t is inside userMap and get their ID. Then create new Event records to this users. 
               }
          }
      }
}//end of cloneEvents

==========================================================
List<Event> updateAllEvent = new List<Event>();
for(Event record: queryEvent) {
    for(String initial: record.Attendees__c.split(';')) {
        Id attendeeId = initialsToUserId.get(initial);
        if(attendeeId != null && record.OwnerId != attendeeId) {
         Event e = new Event();
         e.Subject = record.Subject;
         e.OwnerId = attendeeId;
         e.StartDateTime = record.StartDateTime;
         e.EndDateTime = record.EndDateTime;
         e.Description = record.Description;

         updateAllEvent.add(e);  
         System.debug('updateALLEvent' + updateAllEvent);
      }    
    }
  }// end of query

    Insert updateAllEvent;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a map to identify users quickly, and you'll want to start by gathering the Initials first, *then* getting the users. I call this the "[Aggregate Query Update](https://sfdcfox.blogspot.com/2017/03/the-aggregate-query-update-pattern.html)" programming pattern.

```
Event[] queryEvent = [
  SELECT Attendees__c FROM Event WHERE Id = :activityId AND Attendees__c != NULL];
Map<String, Id> initialToUserId = new Map<String, Id>();
Set<String> initials = new Set<String>();
for(Event record: queryEvent) {
    initials.addAll(record.Attendees__c.split(';'));
}
for(User record: [SELECT Initials__c FROM User WHERE Initials__c = :initials AND IsActive = TRUE]) {
  initialsToUserId.put(record.Initials__c, record.Id);
}
for(Event record: queryEvent) {
    for(String initial: record.Attendees__c.split(';')) {
        Id attendeeId = initialsToUserId.get(initial);
        if(attendeeId != null) {
           // Do something for this user
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This will help immensely. Also, thank you for the site. I will bookmark it.

Comment: @sfdcfox using soql in for loop is best practice or not?

Comment: @Rahul There's often confusion about what the "do not SOQL in a loop" advice means. The syntax here is the [SOQL For Loop](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_loops_for_SOQL.htm), which is preferred when possible (better CPU time, less heap usage). The anti-pattern is when you put a query *inside* the loop (`for(...) { doQuery(); }`), which is definitely a no-no.

Comment: fox, I tried inserting/creating record but it is not creating the record at all after  Insert updateAllEvent. I see everything in the debug being printed fine. I have updated the code above.